# Postgres ltree : How to limit the max number of children at any given level?

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I'm working on a reddit-like application that has comment trees, and am in the process of adding tree-paging: IE instead of returning the entire tree, I need to limit the number of results returned.

For example:

- The top level might have 15k replies.
- A deeply nested comment might have 2 replies.
- A simple SQL sort and limit will probably only contain the top level.

I need to create a postgres LIMIT query, that can limit the maximum # of children at any given level, to say 10 replies.

Is there any way to do this with ltrees, without doing queries for every single leaf?

Comment: Another way to phrase this, would be how do I use limit and offset with a tree to limit the number of results?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.